# C++ How to initialize an array of objects in the heap

Tags: c++

Given a simple class `MyClass` with a constructor that accepts two `int`, how can I initialize an array of `MyClass` in the *heap*?

I've tried

```
MyClass *classes[2] = { new MyClass(1, 2),
                        new MyClass(1, 2) };
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: The code you posted compiles.

Comment: The array is on the stack though, with pointers on the heap

Comment: @MooingDuck: No: the *pointers* are on the stack, and the objects are on the heap.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I wrote it wrong.  The array _of pointers_ is on the stack, the _objects_ are on the heap.  Either way, he says that isn't what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `std::allocator<MyClass>` for this.

```
std::allocator<MyClass> alloc;
MyClass* ptr = alloc.allocate(2);  //allocate
for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
    alloc.construct(ptr+i, MyClass(1, i)); //construct in C++03
    //alloc.construct(ptr+i, 1, i); //construct in C++11
}

//use

for(int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
    alloc.destroy(ptr+i); //destruct
}
alloc.deallocate(ptr); //deallocate
```

Note that you don't have to construct all that you allocate.

Or, better yet, just use `std::vector`.

[EDIT]
KerrekSB suggested this as simpler:

```
MyClass** ptr = new MyClass*[3];
for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    ptr[i] = new MyClass(1, i);

//use

for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
   delete ptr[i];
delete[] ptr;
```

It's slightly slower access, but much easier to use.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Do you another way to construct an array of objects with varying parameters?  I can't think of one.  (Not that there isn't, I just can't think of it)

Comment: Well, the OP's code is actually correct and does basically that, so I'm not sure where the problem is now...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Since a local, fixed size (array (of pointers) on the stack pointing at (objects on the heap)) wasnt what he wanted, he must want an actual (dynamic array of (objects on the heap)).

Comment: We clearly need parentheses around those sentences :-) Well, the OP should specify her needs; as it stands, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I actually used to parenthesize sentences like that, until people told me to knock it off and rewrite them so they make sense the first time.

Comment: Hehe, but they work! OK, a dynamic array of {objects on the heap} is also easy: `T ** p = new T*[3] { new T(), new T(1), new T('a', false) };`

Comment: @KerrekSB: That has more pointer indirection, but is much simpler, and less error prone.  I'd recommend that.